# call conferencing in android

Tags: android

i want to make conference call through my application, but after some searching in stack overflow and in different forum i find that conferencing is not possible programatically. Is it true? Is there any way to do these things like diconnecting call, call forwarding, call conferencing etc in android application. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no APIs in Android for call forwarding, call conferencing, etc.

Comment: There are many apps in android market where call forwarding is happening. How they did it possible? is there any clue.. Links given below are some links of call forwarding app. 1.https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jss.android.forward 2.https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wahooka.fast.forward  3.https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thinkLazy.forgotyourphone

Comment: please refer api level 23 call api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html